# Before and after pseudo elements not working in tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css, pseudo-element

I am using typography plugin that tailwind provides inside my NextJS project.

It displays Content inside the `code` tag with backtick around it. I am trying to remove these backticks. So I tried `.prose code::before {content: "";}` inside my globals.css file but it has no effect. It works when I change it from Firefox style editor.

Any ideas why it is not working?

```css
/* globals.css inside NextJS Project */
.prose code::before {
  content: "";
}

.prose code::after {
  content: "";
}
```

Comment: You need to post the HTML where the CSS is used.  Since you're using tailwind, you should look into enabling sass in Next  so you can use tailwind inside of your css files to keep things consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `!important`, this works for me.

```
/* app.css */
.prose code::before {
    content: "" !important;
}

.prose code::after {
    content: "" !important;
}
```

Comment: Although this would work, I would suggest to have it as last option. Try to increase the specificity by adding one more parent class/node or order of overriding declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in with no CSS file involved.

Just add some customization code in `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      typography: {
        DEFAULT: {
          css: {
            code: {
              '&::before': {
                content: 'none !important',
              },
              '&::after': {
                content: 'none !important',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    // ...
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the pseudo elements before and after. all you have to do is for the content add single quote at the start and end and where there is a space use underscore _ so the code will be something like this

```
<div class="before:content-['i_am_before']" > content</div>
```